# Handle car animation and collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have different **car animation** running on the road which have imported from max. I want to make such an intelligent System that if car start to trigger from another car it become stop. So far I have tried this.

1. Added four collider (as you can see in Fig 1) with tag name car, carBack, carLeft, CarRight
   [image]
2. car left/right contains this code. Added this script to car left,right collider that if this collider hit with car object then car become stop.(And on trigger exit it resume)

   ```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
       {
           if (c.tag == "Car")
           {
               Debug.Log("collided with : carsideTriggerScript :" + c.transform + " - object Name to stop : " + gameObject.name);
               c.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<AnimationControlSpeed>().Speed = 0;
               //StartCoroutine(DecreaseSpeedGradually(transform.gameObject.GetComponent<AnimationControlSpeed>()));
           }
       }

       void OnTriggerExit(Collider c)
       {
           if (c.tag == "Car")
           {
               Debug.Log("Exi collided with :  carsideTriggerScript:" + c.transform + " - object Name to resume : " + gameObject.name);
                c.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<AnimationControlSpeed>().Speed = 1;
           }
       }
   ```
3. Added script which check that if car start to collide with carBack collider then stop (And on trigger exit it resume. Same script as above).

   But a scenario is creating which you can see in fig 2.

[image]

I am enable to handle it. it seems that one car collider hitting  carRightCollider and same thing happen with another car so that both car become stop and unable to move again.
     How can i control it? as same scripts are attached to every gameobject with same OntriggerEnter and logic.

Comment: looks like you need a sphere or capsule collider

Comment: why? what is the reason

Comment: you have gaps between your colliders, either create one large collider, or ensure that the existing colliders overlap

Answer (score 0):

So, after reading your question a few more times I think I understand now. You have two cars and when they collide, they both stop. You want just one car to stop, and one car to go.

If you don't care which one goes first, that's easiest.  You will need a collection to act as a queue to hold all the cars that collided.  Let's call it the 'resume driving queue'.  If a car collides with another car, stop it, then add it to the queue.  Then based on a timer or other logic, one by one you can take the next car from the queue and if the car is stopped, start it.

If you need to select a 'winner' to see who gets to go, that might get a little more complicated.  A basic example of this might be emergency vehicles like the police or fire cars get priority to go first, and other cars need to wait.  In this case you'll want to give each of your car objects some kind of traffic priority property which is like a die they can roll during a collision to see if they win.  Then you can use the random numbers each car generates to insert them in priority order into your resume driving queue.